# Set up a proxy for the Instagram api in php

Tags: php, instagram

I'm logging into Instagram with the following code and class. But the problem is here. I want to log in with a proxy. But unfortunately the proxy setup code doesn't work. Proxies are healthy and active. But when I set up a proxy it doesn't enter but I get that code
In the PHP class there is a function for logging into Instagram. After logging in to proxy, I can't login to Instagram and face a white screen. Because proxies are safe and cannot be accessed through the proxy setup code.

```
include 'class.php';

$username = '';  
$password = '';   

$insta = new instagram();
$insta->setProxy('http://217.106.239.125:10241');
$insta->Login($username, $password);
```

please help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We'll need more information to properly help you: what specifically is going wrong, and do you have a minimal working example of the issue? We need to know what's inside class.php, that libraries are being used, etc. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [Creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).